# Django Rest framework JWT with custom model and fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using Django Rest framework JWT.
My problem is that I have to generate token based on other model rather than auth_user.

For example, there is a model "Program" and it has fields "api_key" and "token".
I want to generate JWT from these fields rather than "username" and "password" of "auth_user".

Is there any easy way to do this?

Best Regards

Comment: You want to use Token base authentication but don't know how to generate token ? right

Comment: You need to customize `JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER`

Comment: @dikamilo Thanks, but not sure how to do. Could you please give me some example?